# What do I need to do to get $broadcast running?

Tags: angularjs

I have been working with the excelent [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) plugin for angular.

When setting it up you can declare a `$scope-node` connected to the `localstorage` like this:

```
$scope.$store = $localStorage;
```

`$scope.$store` is now accessible in all controllers etc.

I want to remove some stuff from `localstorage` and access it using broadcast instead.

In my init I performed:

```
$scope.taskarr = [];
$rootScope.$broadcast('taskarrbroad',$scope.taskarr);
```

What is required in order to `add`, `remove` and `$watch` this array, none of the mentioned seem to work.

Here, nothing happens

```
controller('textController', function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.$watch('taskarrbroad.length', function(){
        console.log($scope.taskarr.map(function(task){
            return task.content;
        }).join('\n'));

    })
})
```

Here I can access `$scope.taskarr` and update it, but the view isn't updated. `$scope.$apply()` didn't help either (the timeout is because it's already within a digest.

```
controller('stateSwitchController', function($scope, $routeParams, $timeout){
    $scope.taskarr = $scope.$store[$routeParams.state].taskarr || [];
        console.log($scope.taskarr);
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply();
    })
}).
```

Comment: "I now expect it to be possible to add, remove and $watch this array". Why? Just because you are using `$broadcast`?

Comment: Yes, that is my(obviously invalid)understanding of $broadcast, I might be clearer: What is required in order to add, remove and $watch.

Comment: `$broadcast` is for raising events in the application that are handled by using `$on`.  It is not a storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`$broadcast` is a way to send events to other parts of your application. When you broadcast an event, someone else has to listen to that even with `$on()`. Something like:

```
// Some controller
$rootScope.$broadcast('my-event', eventData);

// Some other controller
$scope.$on('my-event', function() {
  console.log('my-event fired!')
});
```

`$watch` is something else, it's not an event listener per se, it's a way to attach a function that gets called when that value changes, and that value has to be on the scope. So your watch should look like this:

```
$scope.$watch('taskarr.length', function(){

});
```

Since you've named the array `taskarr` on the scope.